# jquery js post variable set and get for post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to send some parameters from a php page to another to post email dynamically,

if I send the value as hardcoded is ok, but if i send the value on a textfield, it doesnt work,

here the code

page that request post of mail

```
<script>
$otroYa = other.val();
console.log (other.val()); //shows value ok of this var!
$.post( "send-mail-parklane-suscrib.php" , {otro: "ss9", otro2: $otroYa });
</script>
```

so,

> otro2 = $otroYa

doesnt get set? , but hardcoding otro, is ok

php page called to perform post

```
<html>
<head><title>PHP Mail Sender</title></head>
<body>
<?php
session_start(); 
echo("chamb");
$to = 'juanma@gmail.com';
$from = 'bot@prklanefinancial.com.au';
$subject = 'Prklane Financial Subscribe';
$headers = 'From: bot@prklanefinancial.com.au' . "\r\n".
'Reply-To: test@abc.com'. "\r\n".
'Return-Path: test@abc.com' . "\r\n".
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$message = "SS9 tkt ss9!!!";
$name=$_POST['otro2'];  
mail($to, $subject, $name, $headers, "-f $from");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

so if I send my mail with the value

> $name=$_POST['otro2'];

is empty

but using the hardcoded

> $name=$_POST['otro'];

is ok

how to set the var?

thanks!

Comment: If you try console.log ($otroYa) instead do you get the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up PHP & JavaScript .

Instead of

```
$otroYa = other.val();
```

It should be:

```
var otroYa = other.val();
```

and the jquery post request should be:

```
$.post( "send-mail-parklane-suscrib.php" , {otro: "ss9", otro2: otroYa });
```

Comment: Actually $ can be just a part of variable name in js and lack of var here is not a case also as it just causes global scope for this variable...